# Make svg border width constant inspit of image scale

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an svg file as following:

[image: SVG File]

The width of the lines are about 3 and 5 px. The problem is, when the size of the svg image on my site changes (Or I zoom or view it on a mobile device), lines gets much thicker like this:

[image: Thick]

I don't want them to get resized but rather maintain their width what ever the size of the image is. How can I do that?

Comment: does your svg have a stroke width property

Comment: @cup_of No. I am using it in an image with css: width: 100%;height: auto;

Comment: SVG TIny 1.2 and the upcoming SVG 2 define an attribute `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"` for that. Unfortunately, an [issue](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/coords.html#issue31) gives the status of this feature as "at risk of being dropped from SVG 2 due to a lack of implementations."